# Is it more efficient to manipulate netlogo pcolor RGB directly?

Tags: netlogo

I often use the patches to manipulate bitmaps usually by having each patch own a R, G, and a B like this

```
 patches-own [R G B]
```

and using

```
 ask patches [set pcolor rgb R G B]
```

to display. The problem here is that I effectively store each variable twice. once in the patches R G and B and once in each patch's Pcolor. I use very large arrays so any efficiency is welcome.

I would like to start using just the Pcolor without the extra variables but worry that the list stored rgb pcolor is imprecise like regular pcolor. I Also worry that the chicanery I will have to use access the Pcolor list will bog things down.

i.e. is

```
set pcolor pcolor replace-item 1 100
```

better than

```
set b 100
set pcolor rgb 0 100 0
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the memory used by the variables will almost certainly be negligible unless you have a crazy number of patches, and in that case, you will probably have bigger problems.

That said, when you do `set pcolor rgb 0 100 0`, you are really just setting `pcolor` to the list `[0 100 0]`. There is no loss of precision in the numbers:

```
> ask patch 0 0 [ set pcolor [0.123 45.678 99] show pcolor ]
(patch 0 0): [0.123 45.678 99]
```

The only exception is if the components are greater than 255 or less than 0.

Comment: That's a lot, but should be fine. Are you seeing memory problems? That is, have you gotten an out of memory error?

Comment: I did at larger sizes and I would like to get back to them

Comment: Try raising the memory limit as described in the [faq](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#howbig). Don't worry about the first paragraph unless you're on 32bit Windows XP or something; I and many others regularly run multi-gigabyte models.